# Pagination response from API in Loop for R

Tags: r, function, api, dplyr

I am working on an API where response is limited to 100 rows at max but in the list it returns, it gives away the link to the next page.

Example:

```
> apiresponse$paging
$`next`
[1] "https://workable.com/spi/v3/accounts/xx-xx-xx-xx/jobs?limit=100&since_id=1233xxb"
```

So, to get data from next page, I have to add the above mentioned URL to call API.

**API Code**

```
url = "https://workable.com/spi/v3/accounts/xx-xx-xx-xx/jobs?limit=100"
key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# OPTION 1
x <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key, sep = " ")))

this.raw.content <- rawToChar(x$content)

apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)


apiresponse$paging
apidata <- apiresponse$jobs
```

**Requirement**
I would probably like a function where the **NEXT URL** would automatically get into API calling a loop until all data is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `while` loop and capture the data until `next` is not null.

```
url = "https://workable.com/spi/v3/accounts/xx-xx-xx-xx/jobs?limit=100"
key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# OPTION 1
x <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key, sep = " ")))
this.raw.content <- rawToChar(x$content)
apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)
next_url <- apiresponse$paging$`next`
apidata <- apiresponse$jobs

data <- list()
i <- 1

while(!is.null(next_url)) {
  x <- GET(apiresponse$paging$`next`, 
           add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key, sep = " ")))
  this.raw.content <- rawToChar(x$content)
  apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)
  next_url <- apiresponse$paging$`next`
  temp <- apiresponse$jobs
  rownames(temp) <- NULL
  data[[i]] <- temp
  i <- i + 1
}

result <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Comment: Hi @ronakshah, it seems to be giving output as a list whereas ideally i want an rbinded data.frame.

Comment: Yes, I added `result <- do.call(rbind, data)` in the end to get one combined dataframe.

Comment: I see, what seems to be happening is, duplicated row names and hence it is returning an error ``Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed``

Comment: Well, it's difficult to help without something to work on since we can't be sure if the answer works but maybe try to remove rownames from data. See the updated answer.

Comment: your code basically works, I will find out a solution to this row names problem. Thank you